# onDestory Is Not Called If an Application Is Cleared When It Is Paused

Tags: android

[image]

I overrode `onDestroy` in `MainActivity` of my app (`Acards`).

If I clear all processes (click `Clear all`) when my app is paused (when I recently use another app), the `onDestroy` is not called.

How can I call the `onDestroy` when my app is paused and cleared?

Answer (score 1):

When you clear app from recents, the whole process will be killed and all threads associated with the process will also be killed. So you cannot create a callback for clearing app from recents.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there's never a guarantee that onDestroy() will be called, and in some cases processes such as your app will be killed directly, bypassing the method call anyway.

According to this link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29

> protected void onDestroy ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Perform any final cleanup before an activity is
>   destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing
>   (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily
>   destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can
>   distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.
>
> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving
>   data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content
>   provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here. This method is usually
>   implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an
>   activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things
>   around while the rest of its application is still running. There are
>   situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting
>   process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it
>   should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.

However, You can move your code to onPause() or onStop()